# How do database migrations in Moqui work?

Tags: liquibase, moqui

Assuming that a instance of Moqui has gone production e.g. has customer data inside it and has a few tenants, what is the standard practice of upgrading the databases, such as from [one release of Mantle to the next](https://github.com/moqui/mantle/compare/release-0.5.1...release-0.5.2) and how does this all tie in with Liquibase?

Comment: This might be better as a discussion on LinkedIn rather than a question here as it is not about a current feature or specific how-to. Right now the Entity Facade can add tables, columns, indexes, relationships, etc at runtime. Other database changes such as renaming tables and columns, dropping various things, merging columns, etc can be done through Liquibase but there is no meta data in Mantle right now to describe such changes, and I don't plan to maintain that sort of thing unless entities are used in Mantle/etc services, and only starting after the soon to be released 1.0 version.

Comment: Thanks David - I have added this topic on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Database-Migrations-4640689.S.5978425069334978562)